# Error de core al conectarme al api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando conectarme a una api que me devuelve unos datos del cliente he utilizado todas las formas para conectarme pero siempre me sale el mismo error, para conectarme por ejemplo he utilizado la funcion de javascript .ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://app.system.com/sistemas/consultaCliente/0926949066",   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
    },

    failure: function (data) {
       console.log("failure");
    }, 
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://app.system.com/sistemas/consultaCliente/0926949066' from
>   origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource."

he buscado bastante y aun no encuentro el error espero me ayuden gracias

Answer (score 0):

Son errores de llamadas cruzadas. En palabras simples, no se aceptan llamadas de origenes desconocidos y son bloqueadas, si el dominio `app.system.com` no acepta llamadas del servidor de donde estas llamando (o alomejor es tu localhost) tienes que configurar el servidor para que si las acepte, lo que puedes hacer por mientras si necesitas desarrollar es instalar un plugin de chrome que simula estar el mismo servidor. [Cors chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Comment: instalé el plugin y ahora me sale este error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app.system.com/sistemas/consultaCliente/0926949066' from origin 'https://es.stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: por que estas llamando desde stack over flow? prueba desde tu proyecto

Comment: el problema es que la debo llamar desde una pagina de un cliente

Comment: Como te dije en mi respuesta, para pruebas puedes ocupar el plugin ejecutando desde tu local, pero cuando debas hacer el llamado desde el cliente el servidor debe aceptar llamadas desde tu cliente, osino, no funcionara.